# Import a dynamic graph into Latex/Beamer

Tags: r, graph, latex, interactive

I'm wondering whether it exists a way to import into a beamer presentation an interactive graph done with R.
For example i have this code:

```
library(manipulate)
x <- seq(from = 1, to = 10, by = 1)
manipulate(plot(x,exp(-theta)*((theta^x)/factorial(x)), ylim=c(0,0.3)),theta =slider(0,100))
```

It's a interactive graphs that shows a Poisson distribution and I can change the parameter theta.
What I'd like to do is to put this into a frame in Latex and build a presentaion which there's the plot and slider and I can interact with it.

Basically I don't want to open R and show there, I'd like to have it everything into beamer.

Thank you.

Comment: You're using beamer to make a PDF i assume? You want some sort of interactive PDF file?

Comment: Yes I want this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you just can't do that with PDFs in general so R isn't going to help you there. Maybe instead look at shiny to create interactive presentations. See: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether what you have in mind is possible in Latex. As a workaround, you can save graphic files for the 10 x values and include them as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\frame{
\animategraphics[controls,width=\linewidth]{1}{plot_}{1}{10}
}
\end{document}
```